# Can't change webflux default connection timeout value?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have webflux client configuration like this

```
 TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient
            .create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, customProperties.getRequestTimeout())
            .doOnConnected(connection -> {
                connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(customProperties.getResponseTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                connection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(customProperties.getRequestTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            });
```

I tried to change value of my response timeout(set to 60000) but connection close after 10000ms (with default value)
How to change this connection timeout value?